# Get locking state of configuration section IIS

Tags: iis

Is there any way to check if a config section is locked or not in IIS. Any kind of command is ok (cmd, vbscript)

This is my first time asking in this website. I'm very appreciated for any reply. Thanks very much!

Comment: Do you mean the web.config?

Answer (score 0):

It can be locked a couple different ways, but the easy way that works most times is in IIS Manager at the server level. Check "Feature Delegation". That shows the section types. If it's Read Only then it's locked. You can check the same at the site or folder level.

I've rarely found that admins change that, so 99.9% of the time the Feature Delegation settings should properly reflect the setting.

Another way within IIS Manager is to visit the section and see if the status bar in the bottom left says that it's a change to web.config (not locked) or applicationHost.config (locked).

And of course you could try to make the change in web.config and see if the site blows up.

To check for the rarely exception (a server admin updates the server), check administration.config where the delegation and lock settings are applied.